# Enable bind/front end listening IP in Haproxy Tcp Log?

Tags: haproxy

How to enable local bind address ip in haproxy log ?.

My Haproxy Config:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
        daemon

defaults
        log     global
        mode    tcp
        option  tcplog
        option  dontlognull

backend app1_80
        server app1_443 127.0.0.1:443

frontend app1_443
    bind 10.11.12.202:443
    bind 10.11.12.203:443
    bind 10.11.12.204:443
    default_backend app1_80
```

Sample Log entry:

```
172.20.1.16:1527 [10/Feb/2016:07:46:43.885] app1_443 app1_80/app1_443 1/1067/2890 11105 -- 96/96/96/96/0 0/0
172.20.1.28:1526 [10/Feb/2016:07:46:42.982] app1_443 app1_80/app1_443 1/70/3823 85722 CD 95/95/95/95/0 0/0
172.20.1.49:1529 [10/Feb/2016:07:46:44.249] app1_443 app1_80/app1_443 1/80/2623 15097 -- 94/94/94/94/0 0/0
```

Here You can see , I received request from different IP's [ means from different department].

But From my logs, I couldn't get, to which destination IP that request has comes either 10.11.12.202 or 10.11.12.203 or 10.11.12.204.

Is there any option available in Haproxy tcp logformat to enable Destination IP address [ Mean "Bind IP Address" ] in log ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using tcplog, the frontend ip is not captured in the default log format. What I usually do is declare a custom log format and specify what I want logged.
 The default tcp log format for haproxy v1.5 is:
    log-format %ci:%cp\ [%t]\ %ft\ %b/%s\ %Tw/%Tc/%Tt\ %B\ %ts\ \
               %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq

The value you are looking for is stored in %fi and %fp for frontend IP and frontend Port respectively.

```
frontend app1_443
bind 10.11.12.202:443
bind 10.11.12.203:443
bind 10.11.12.204:443
log-format %ci:%cp\ [%t]\ %fi\ %ft\ %b/%s\ %Tw/%Tc/%Tt\ %B\ %ts\ \
           %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc\ %sq/%bq
default_backend app1_80
```

The addition of %fi places the frontend ip just before the name (app1_443).